# Tools for fast searching operations in a very large C# code-base

Tags: c#, .net, search, indexing, codebase

I wondered if someone knows some hassle free tools for indexing/searching a very large C# code base. By "very large" I mean about 50 solutions with 10 to 80 projects underneath. The SLOC count is about 40 - 50 million (rough estimation).

I am aware that Resharper for VS has decent search options, at least inside a solution, but I am looking for something to index the whole code-base. Lot of people here waste time searching for class *x* or API *y* and a indexing search tool would lift the burden.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Windows indexing doesn't work? Or whatever OS?

Comment: Windows indexed search is what we use now, but it indexes the codebase locally -> every man for himself. We wanted to have the code base indexed once and everybody can access it. Since our code base is under constant change is also wiser to have the indexing in a central point, in our case the last integration gate (production/shipping branch).

Comment: OpenGrok sound like what i've been searching for. Thanks!

Comment: You can try CodeQuery. It doesn't say C# but it might still work. https://github.com/ruben2020/codequery  Disclaimer: It's my project.

Comment: hi Ruben, thanks for your tip. I will have a look! Btw. it doesn't matter if it is your project, self-advertisement is cool with me  as long as the product does what it advertises :). Again thanks for the tip! Regards, zhengtonic